# Get the current month, then display a dynamic index page

Tags: php, date, calendar

I have five files, namely `index.php` and `first.php .. fourth.php`.

`first.php` through `fourth.php` represent an annual calendar divided into 4 quarters (3 months per file). Now, I just need to display within the index page the current quarter. For example, since it's August, my index should display `third.php`, which contains July, August and September. In short, I need to make my index page dynamic.

This is my current code, which is obviously static:

```
   if(!isset($_GET['quarter']) && !isset($_GET['year'])){
    include ('/thirdq2012.php');
    }
```

Also, how would I test this?

EDIT: problem fixed! i have another question, on top of every page, i have a drop down year button, which switches from 2011, 2012, 2013. my next problem is how to display the specific quarter for the selected year without creating multiple files? example quarter 1(january, february, march) of year 2011 contains data and other values that the user input, but quarter 1 of year 2012 doesnt contain anything. how will i switch on from there?

Comment: You want to decide which page to display based on the current date?

Comment: Obtain the current date/month and use a switch to include the proper file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<?php

    $now   = new DateTime();
    $month = (int)$now->format("m");

    if ($month >= 1 AND $month <= 3) {
        echo "First Quarter!";
    }
    elseif ($month >= 4 AND $month <= 6) {
        echo "Second Quarter!";
    }
    elseif ($month >= 7 AND $month <= 9) {
        echo "Third Quarter!";
    }
    else {
        echo "Fourth Quarter!";
    }
```

Comment: thanks sir. it worked to perfection. i have another question, on top of every page, i have a drop down year button, which switches from 2011, 2012, 2013. my next problem is how to display the specific quarter for the selected year without creating multiple files?

example quarter 1(january, february, march) of year 2011 contains data and other values that the user input, but quarter 1 of year 2012 doesnt contain anything. how will i switch on from there?

Comment: this my code in the links:

    <li><a href="index.php?year=2011"><img src="images/2011BW.jpg" width="74" height="38"/></a><ul>
        <li><a href="index.php?year=2013"><img src="images/2013.jpg" width="74" height="38" /></a>

Comment: @jet if you have another question please [ask it in a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You are unlikely to get the help you are looking for by asking further questions in comments.